# Failed to find /usr/local/Cellar/mesos/0.22.1/etc/mesos/masters

Tags: apache-spark, mesos, mesosphere

I installed mesos on mac using brew . After the installation i went to mesos/0.22.1/sbin folder and tried to execute mesos-start-master.sh . 
but it failed with

```
error : Failed to find /usr/local/Cellar/mesos/0.22.1/etc/mesos/masters
```

My question is how is this etc folder generated. After installation . I can type mesos on cmd and work .But i need to execute above mentioned  sh file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The etc folder should be created when you install mesos via brew. Just create a text file with each mesos master per line.

`echo $(hostname) >> /usr/local/Cellar/mesos/0.22.1/etc/mesos/master`